# Django Rest Framework - display prepopulated slug field

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a `slug` field for a model that I would like returned in the object representation but **NOT** as part of the form input in the browsable API. It is generated by a `slugify` method on the model.

When I mark it as read only in it's `ModelSerializer` by adding it to `Meta` using `read_only_fields=('slug',)` trying to add new fields in the browseable api form yields `"This field is required."`

The serializer for reference is below:

```
class CategorySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    slug = serializers.SlugField(read_only=True, required=False)

    def to_representation(self, obj):
        self.fields['children'] = CategorySerializer(obj, many=True, read_only=True)
        return super(CategorySerializer, self).to_representation(obj)

    class Meta:
        model = Category
        fields = ('pk', 'url', 'title', 'slug', 'parent', 'children', 'active', 'icon')
        read_only_fields = ('children','slug',)
```

What is a simple solution to show the field in the representation and not the browseable api form given the above?

For reference, here is my model:

```
@python_2_unicode_compatible
class CategoryBase(mptt_models.MPTTModel):
    parent = mptt_fields.TreeForeignKey( 'self', blank=True, null=True, related_name='children', verbose_name=_('parent'))
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100, verbose_name=_('name'))
    slug = models.SlugField(verbose_name=_('slug'), null=True)
    active = models.BooleanField(default=True, verbose_name=_('active'))

    objects = CategoryManager()
    tree = TreeManager()

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        """
        While you can activate an item without activating its descendants,
        It doesn't make sense that you can deactivate an item and have its
        decendants remain active.
        """
        if not self.slug:
            self.slug = slugify(self.title)

        super(CategoryBase, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

        if not self.active:
            for item in self.get_descendants():
                if item.active != self.active:
                    item.active = self.active
                    item.save()

    def __str__(self):
        ancestors = self.get_ancestors()
        return ' > '.join([force_text(i.title) for i in ancestors] + [self.title, ])

    class Meta:
        abstract = True
        unique_together = ('parent', 'slug')
        ordering = ('tree_id', 'lft')

    class MPTTMeta:
        order_insertion_by = 'title'


class Category(CategoryBase):
    icon = IconField(null=True, blank=True)
    order = models.IntegerField(default=0)

    @property
    def short_title(self):
        return self.title

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        """Return a path"""
        from django.core.urlresolvers import NoReverseMatch
        try:
            prefix = reverse('categories_tree_list')
        except NoReverseMatch:
            prefix = '/'
        ancestors = list(self.get_ancestors()) + [self, ]
        return prefix + '/'.join([force_text(i.slug) for i in ancestors]) + '/'

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Category, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

    class Meta(CategoryBase.Meta):
        verbose_name = _('category')
        verbose_name_plural = _('categories')
```

Comment: Make sure your model definition doesn't override `required=False`. That is, make sure you have a sensible default or you have `null=True`

Comment: model definition is already set to `null=True` which is what is confusing me